# how to update specific record in cache in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I am working on a project but I am not quite sure how to update a single record stored in the cache, for example:

**PostController.php**

```
class PostController extends Controller
   public function index(){
       $page = request('page', 1);
       $posts = Cache::rememberForever('posts_page_'.$page, function(){
            return Posts::query()            
                ->with('category')
                ->latest()
                ->paginate(30);

        });    
   }
...
...
}
```

Here is the store method:

```
public function store(PostCreateRequest $request)
    {                                             
            $post = Post::create([
                'title' => $request->title,                        
                'body' => $request->body,
                ...
                 ...
                'category_id' => $request->category_id
            ]);            

            ....
            ....
     
            Cache::flush(); 
            
            return redirect()->route('posts.index')
                ->with('success', 'post created');

            

    }
```

I need to do **Cache::flush();** to clean all the posts cache, because I have this keys in the cache: posts_page_1, posts_page_2, posts_page_3, etc, category_name1_page_1, category_name1_page_2, category_name2_page_1, etc..

But I am adding only one post, the same occurs when I update only one post, I have to clean up all the cache, what would happen if I had thousands or millions records? that **Cache::flush()** would take to much time, I would like to know how to add or update one specific record in the cache, I am using currently the file driver for caching. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your are not storing **many posts** your are storing **the result of a query**, so any time you use the `index()` method you are retrieving a cached response.

First you can face this "issue" by **avoiding the use of** `rememberForever()`.

Why? Because every time you have to manually clear the cache, if you forgot items you can easily end with many MB of data **forgotten in the cache**.

Maybe changing your method to:

```php
$seconds = 300; // A default clearing time

Cache::remember('posts_page_'.$page, $seconds, function(){
  return Posts::query()            
    ->with('category')
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(30);
});
```

Also [in the docs says](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache#removing-items-from-the-cache) many ways to clear cache. Maybe use:

```php
Cache::forget('posts_page_'.$page);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I was using Cache::remember, but the problem is that every x seconds, minutes or hours, the cache will be cleaned even if there is no changes in the data, so I wanted to avoid hit the database often. I was also using cache::forget('posts_page_'.$page), but there are many pages, I need to put it in a loop, also with categories, that's why I used Cache::flush()

Comment: The problem of unlimited time cache is that the developer MUST clear the cache every time in the code, by using a default timeout you ensure consistency in your data. If you or someone forgets to clear cache, in X seconds it will get auto cleared. I think is better to hit the DB often than potentially forgetting to clear cache. DB can support that flow and user won't even notice any performance difference.